# Why i get one day plus for ToDate when pass date parameter to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

Hi i am a little bit confused about passing parameters values from my portal to SSRS report. For example i have `Start` and `EndDate` parameters which i get from dropdown menu in my portal and pass those values to SSRS. But in SSRS EndDate is not ok, because is add +1 day in the original value. How can i fix this ?

For example my `EndDate` should be

> 2016-06-20 20:00

but i get

> 2016-06-21 20:00

Comment: Please post your formulas

Comment: /BOPortal/Reports/View/Events?FromDate=2016-06-18 22:00:00&ToDate=2016-06-19 21:59:00&Language=en-GB&User=admin&ReportFormat=EXCEL  This is what i send to SSRS. But SSRS return ToDate=2016-06-20 21:59:00.I don't have any formula in SSRS, just i receive ToDate parameter